# Is it possible to derive table name as "NEW.<TABLE FEILD>" in MySql Trigger?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have two tables

COMPANYINFO(SYMBOL, PRICE, PARENTTABLE)

WATCHLIST(SYMBOL, WATCHVALUE)

Whenever the PRICE in COMPANYINFO is updated I need to get maximum value from from the table in PARENTTABLE field of COMPANYINFO and update WATCHVALUE of WATCHLIST table.

The trigger I defined in COMPANYINFO is as follows

`BEGIN
UPDATE WATCHLIST SET WATCHVALUE= (SELECT MAX(WATCHVALUE) FROM NEW.PARENTTABLE) WHERE SYMBOL = NEW.SYMBOL;
END`

The database is not taking the NEW.PARENTTABLE value rather trying to take PARENTTABLE table of NEW database. Is it possible to make the trigger take the field value. I cannot use dynamic query as it is not allowed in MySql trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use a value as the name of a table. The name of a table must be fixed at the time the SQL statement is parsed.

You could use a CASE statement for each possible parent table name, and query the max from the respective table.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE MAX_VALUE NUMERIC(9,2);

CASE NEW.PARENTTABLE
 WHEN 'table1' THEN SELECT MAX(WATCHVALUE) INTO MAX_VALUE FROM table1;
 WHEN 'table2' THEN SELECT MAX(WATCHVALUE) INTO MAX_VALUE FROM table2;
 ...others...
END CASE;

UPDATE WATCHLIST SET WATCHVALUE = MAX_VALUE WHERE SYMBOL = NEW.SYMBOL;
END
```

I think your data model may not be designed well if you need to reference a variety of tables. Sounds fishy.

---

Re your comment:

You need to not have a different table for each symbol. That's the root cause of the fishy pattern in your  database design. I called it "Metadata Tribbles" in my book [SQL Antipatterns](https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

Comment: I cannot use CASE as there are hundreds of tables and new table comes frequently. The table name is also fixed since each row has a particular table from where to update. But the problem is each row has different table from where the aggregate value is fetched and depends on symbol. For example if symbol is "ABC" than table name is "ABCDAY", if "ACD" than table name is "ACDDAY". Just need to append "DAY" at the end of the name. It will also work is somehow I concat "NEW.SYMBOL+DAY" instead of taking PARENTTABLE field.